# GameKit iOS5 - handle timeout for turn-based games

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

In iOS6 I can specify the timeout that the next player must complete his turn, using this function:
endTurnWithNextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler.

However, the timeout property doesn't exist in iOS5.

Since I want to support iOS5 as well, how can I specify that timeout in iOS5? Without this, the player can simply not play forever, and the game will be stuck without ending properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, you are stuck if you’re supporting iOS 5.

One thing that might help is to use a local notification to remind a player to take their turn. (You’d cancel it when they do.) This won’t give quite the same user experience, but since most of your players will be on iOS 6, you could assume that at twice the timeout value, the iOS 5 player should have moved, and remind them to check on their current match.